# Facing issue with Date column format in Power BI

Tags: powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I have an excel dateset where date column includes date in dd-mm-yyyy format(Proper date) and in text format that too in mm/dd/yyyy format(just text not proper date). want to convert all dates in dd-mm-yyyy format. How to do all in dd-mm-yyyy format in Power Query editor

The question is: In Power Query Editor Perform all necessary action to convert all the dates in the "Date" column to be in "dd-mm-yyyy" format.

I am new in Power BI. Please help on this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCzAy.png)

Comment: below is part of the date column. data is there in this way.                                             Order Date
7/27/2012
9/14/2013
5/15/2015
5/17/2017
10/26/2016
11-07-2011
1/18/2013
11/30/2016
3/23/2017
5/23/2016
02-09-2014
2/18/2011
1/28/2013
6/20/2011
04-04-2010
6/19/2014
3/28/2011
07-07-2011
12-07-2015
1/19/2011
12/31/2010
10/28/2015
4/13/2015
05-01-2015
8/25/2011
02-10-2016
2/28/2015
6/13/2011
6/23/2012
09-01-2011
11/13/2014
11-03-2013
12-05-2016
09-08-2013
3/22/2014
11-01-2011
1/15/2016
11/29/2010
11/19/2011
07-06-2016
11-11-2015
5/28/2013

Answer (score 1):

## Importing correctly

If you set the right culture, all the inputs are converted to a `type date`

```
let
    Source = #table(
        type table[Date = text],
        { {"7/27/2012"}, {"9/14/2020"}, {"04-11-2020"} }
    ),

    // using the system's current culture
    #"Dates" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(
        Source,
        { {"Date", type date} }
    ),

    //specify a specific culture
    #"US Dates" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(
        Source,
        { {"Date", type date} },
        "en-US"
    )
in
    #"US Dates"
```

## date verses text

I'm not clear if you're referring to different date format strings, or actual data types when you say `Proper Date`, I think you mean the first.

In the query editor where you import dates, it should be `type date`
If it visually displays out of order, **that's okay**. It's using your systems current settings.

Once you're in the `data model`, that is when you pick your date format strings. Notice that **both images use the same data**, the green is the data type in Power Query.

Blue is the `format string` that lets you override the defaults.

[image]